# Implications of Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots

Rolle's Theorem states that for any function continuous on an interval $[a,b]$, and differentiable on its interior, if $f(a) = f(b) = 0$, then $\exists c ∈ [a,b]$ such that $f'(c) = 0$.

---

I believe that we can therefore conclude that,

> (1) If $f(x)$ has $n$ roots, then $f'(x)$ has at least $n-1$ roots,
>
> (2) If $f'(x)$ has $n-1$ roots, then $f(x)$ can have at most $ n$ roots

Is that true?

---

Also, are these two statements enough to encompass all possibilities, given information about the roots of either f(x) or f'(x)?

For instance, if we know $f(x)$ has at least $3$ roots, then we can conclude that $f'(x)$ must have at least $2$ roots from $(1)$. Or, if we are told that $f'(x)$ has at most $4$ roots, $f(x)$ cannot have more than $5$ from (2).

Are they any possibilities that would be left out from only these $2$ cases?

Thanks!

Comment: Rolle's Theorem requires the function to be differentiable on the interval.  Consider $f(x) = |1-x| \text{ on } [0, 2]$.

Comment: @RobertShore Thanks. I've added that in

Comment: The statement of Rolle's Theorem is a little bit stronger: it states that such $c$ can be found in the *interior* of the interval $[a,b]$. And you need this stronger version to conclude (1).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you say is true and it is very useful to have that in mind, well done ! But be careful, $f$ also has to be differentiable on $]a, b[$.

A good application of this is for real polynomials. For instance, it is a good exercice to show that if $P\in\mathbb{R}[X]$ has $\deg P$ real roots counted with multiplicity, then $P'$ has $\deg P - 1$ real roots counted with multiplicity.

Comment: But, can't P' actually have more than P-1 roots?

Comment: No : because deg P' = deg P -1, so it can have at most deg P -1 roots.